$A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear mapping. $V$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. $A(V)$ is open in $A(\mathbb{R}^n)$. (Walter Rudin)
I am reading "Principles of Mathematical Analysis Third Edition" by Walter Rudin.
The author says

Since $V$ is open, it is clear that $A(V)$ is an open subset of its range $\mathcal{R}(A)=Y_1$

and he didn't prove the following proposition:

Suppose $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear mapping whose rank is $r$.
Suppose $V$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then, $A(V)$ is open in $A(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

At first glance, I thought this proposition is very easy to prove, but somehow I could not prove it.
My attempt:
I need to prove the following:

For any $y_0\in A(V)$, there is a positive real number $\varepsilon$ such that if $|y-y_0|<\varepsilon$ and $y\in A(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $y\in A(V)$.

Equivalently, I need to prove the following:

For any $x_0\in V$, there is a positive real number $\varepsilon$ such that if $|y-Ax_0|<\varepsilon$ and $y\in A(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then there is $x\in V$ such that $y=Ax$.

Let $y\in A(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Then, there is $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $y=Ax$.
The map $f:y\mapsto x+\ker A$ is well-defined.
I want to prove the following:

If $y\in A(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is very close to $Ax_0$, then $f(y)\cap V$ is not empty.



What is the topology/norm here?

Maybe it's helpful to rephrase it as "if $A$ is surjective then $A(V)$ is open in $\Bbb R^m$". Can you show that this is true in the special case $V = (0, 1)^n$?

@user469053, in the context of real analysis I think it's fair to assume that the topology on $\Bbb R$ is the Euclidean one.

@IzaakvanDongen I would never assume when I can ask.

Let $V:=(0,1)^n$. Let $Ae_{i_1},\dots,Ae_{i_r}$ be a basis of $A(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $r$ is the dimension of $A(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let $y\in A(V)$. Then there is $a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that $y=a_1A(e_1)+\cdots+a_nA(e_n)$ with $a_i\in (0.1)$. Let $l:=\min{1-a_{i_1},a_{i_1},\dots,1-a_{i_r},a_{i_r}}$. Then $l>0$.

Let $b_{i_1},\dots,b_{i_r}\in (-l,l)$. Then $a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n+b_{i_1}e_{i_1}+\cdots+b_{i_r}e_{i_r}\in V$ and $y+b_{i_1}A(e_{i_1})+\cdots+b_{i_r}A(e_{i_r})\in A(V)$. ${y+b_{i_1}A(e_{i_1})+\cdots+b_{i_r}A(e_{i_r}):b_{i_1},\dots,b_{i_r}\in (-l,l)}$ is an $r$-dimensional parallelepiped centered at point $y$. So, I guess this is open in $A(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

@IzaakvanDongen thank you very much for your very nice hint.

@user469053 thank you very much for your comment.
